# Regex for no repeat special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

My requirement is that no repeat special characters

I currently have

```
const reg=(/[^.*a-zA-Z0-9.,\s]*/g, '')
```

I want to allow

```
sometext . something
```

I do not want to allow

```
sometext,, something . some. some,
```

Comment: Can you clarify why the second example isn't allowed, and be more specific about the rules

Comment: `/[<your special characters>]{2,}/` should be sufficient - you can just check if there are two or more in a row.

no need for the `g`, either, because you want to fail after the first match regardless

Comment: By repeated you mean consecutive or throughout the string  ?

Comment: Use `const reg=(/^(?!.*([^a-zA-Z0-9.,\s])\1)/, '')`. I think you misused `.*` in the character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have a special character repeated in your complete string. You can use `match` and `Set`

```js
let nonRepeated = (str) => {
  let match = str.match(/[.,]/g) || []
  let setMatch = new Set(match)
  return match.length != setMatch.size
}

console.log(nonRepeated('sometext . something'))
console.log(nonRepeated('sometext,, something . some. some,'))
```

And if you don't want to have consecutive special character then you can use do it something like this

```js
let nonRepeated = (str) =>  !/([,.])(?=\1)/.test(str)

console.log(nonRepeated('sometext . something'))
console.log(nonRepeated('sometext,, something . some. some,'))
```